# Cakephp:How to get id of the first form when saving my last of three forms

Tags: cakephp

High guys,I have three models that i am using in Cakephp,I create 3 views for my models which are linked by the second model.The problem is how can i retrieve the id of the first model when i want to do a final save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that you're saving the three models in three separate page requests, it should suffice to simply store the saved model data in your session. That way you can read it in the 2nd and 3rd page request and include the necessary data in your forms and processing.

If you're doing it all in the same request, then Moyed's idea works, you can get the ID of a saved row through the model:

```
$this->Model->save($data);
$saved_row_id = $this->Model->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the id of first model.

If you use the the **save()** method you can get the id like so:

```
$this->Model->save($data);
$id = $this->Model->id;
```

OR

Cake's model class has a function that gets the last inserted id:

```
$this->Model->getLastInsertID()
```

You just need to replace Model with the name of first model